# MYSQL query nested one-to-many relationship into an array element value

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I've been looking for a way to query a nested one-to-many relationship to no avail.

So I have three tables called property, rooms, and utilities which are all connected from their parent primary key as their foreign key.

I'm trying to achieve this output:
[imgur img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmPhr.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to make a database query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: MySQL is for storing and retrieving relational data. This looks more like a JSON encoded array result - so not something you'd typically handle in MySQL (but that's not to say you couldn't)